# Filter array of arrays using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have class called "SMessage";

```
@interface SMessage:NSObject
@property(nonatomic)int messageId;
@end
```

also I can class called SDay;
SDay can has a lot of messages(SMessage);

```
@interface SDay:NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *messages;
@end
```

And in the final I have common class where I have array of days;

```
@interface SCommonClass:NSObject 
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *days;
@end
```

I'm trying filter array of days and find message that has messageId = 100(for example);

And I have no ideas how to do this using NSPredicate;
Thank you for answers;

Comment: Check out http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/07/27/filtering-arrays-with-nspredicate.html.  Also, SO people are a little like Parisians.  They're cool with it if you don't speak French, but you have to try a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    SDay* day = (SDay*)object;
    NSMutableArray* messages = day.messages;
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"messageId == 100"];

    if ([messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }

}];


NSArray* result = [common.days filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

============update===============

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    SDay* day = (SDay*)object;
    NSMutableArray* messages = day.messages;
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"messageID == 100"];
    NSArray *filteredMessages = [messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (filteredMessages.count == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        day.messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:filteredMessages];
        return YES;
    }

}];
```

Comment: You need to customize the predicate block. The code should work.

Comment: Hm..That works a little wrong; When I try to filter array of days I have the following: day1 has two messages(messageId==100, messageId==99); and day2 has just one message(messageId==100); In the result `NSArray* result = [common.days filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];` I received array with two days that have the same messages as before filtering; How should I modify NSPredicate to receive array when I will have two messages(messageId==100)?; Thank you;

Comment: If it is okay to change the messages of your SDay objects. Please see updated answer.